# Fabric js. Не получается задать fill для нескольких объектов

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

Добрый день,
Пожалуйста, подскажите, в чем может быть проблема.

Мой код создает несколько объектов Rects на fabric js канвасе. 
Мне нужно, чтобы все они имели текстуру, поэтому я для каждого объекта в цикле после добавления выполняю следующий код.

```js
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  selectable: true,
  hasControls: false,
  borderColor: 'red',
  borderWidth: 2,
  lockMovementX: true,
  lockMovementY: true
});

canvas.add(rect);

fabric.util.loadImage('construct/css/img/patterns/1.jpg', function(img) {
  rect.set('fill', new fabric.Pattern({
    source: img,
    repeat: 'repeat'
  }));
});
```

По какой-то причине в результате, текстуру получает только один объект, который был создан последним.

Сломал над этим вопросом всю голову и нигде не могу найти решения.

Если кто-то сможет подсказать как забороть эту напасть, заранее благодарю.

Comment: This site is for russian community. To ask questions in english go to [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно сохранить все ваши квадраты в массив и затем пройтись по этому массиву, назначив заливку каждому элементу:

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var rects = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  var rect = new fabric.Rect({
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    top: 0,
    left: 110 * i,
    selectable: true,
    hasControls: false,
    borderColor: 'red',
    borderWidth: 2,
    lockMovementX: true,
    lockMovementY: true
  });
  canvas.add(rect);
  rects.push(rect);
}

fabric.util.loadImage('https://via.placeholder.com/100x100', function(img) {
      rects.forEach(function(r) {
        r.set('fill', new fabric.Pattern({
          source: img,
          repeat: 'repeat'
        }));
      });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.17/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: Хотелось более изящно при создании задавать текстуру. Спасибо Вам большое за помощь. Там асинхронная функция получается да?

Comment: Вы абсолютно правы. Изящнее можно, но под капотом там будет вот этот код всё равно.